# Java: Manipulating non-static variable from thread?

Tags: java, string, multithreading, variables, static

The relevant summary of my code is this:

```
public class A {
    String aString;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        new Thread(b).start();
    }
    public static class B implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            aString = "foo";
        }
    }
}
```

I have had a few months of Java coding experience but `thread` and `dynamic` vs. `static` is still rather new to me.  In order for the thread to execute properly, class B must be static, or else only the thread executes, not both.  My goal is to obviously have the thread execute in the background so that other code that I may have in class A can execute simultaneously.  Problem is, if class B is static, I can't manipulate the string `aString`, as I get the exception `non-static variable aString cannot be referenced from a static context`.

I've looked up information on this but I have not found anything that relates to fixing this issue in threads.  My question is, how can I manipulate `aString` within class B and still get the thread to work properly (both classes running, not just class B)?

Comment: `static` has nothing to do with threads. You would have the same problem without threads. For example, with `new B().run()`. Or if you just wrote `aString = "foo"` in `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your example work, you'll need something like this:

```
public class A {
    volatile String aString;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        A a = new A();
        Thread t = new Thread(a.new B());
        t.start();
        t.join(); // wait for t to finish
        System.out.println(a.aString); // prints "foo"
    }

    class B implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            aString = "foo";
        }
    }
}
```

Resolving the `static` issue is the easy part - see code for how.

I hope the rest of the code helps illustrate some of the issues you need to cater for when using threads.

Comment: Thing is though, I don't want to wait until the thread finishes.  This was just an example code - in the actual program I have `while` loops going on in both classes, hence why I'm using the threads.  I removed `t.join()` but still both threads don't execute at the same time.

Comment: @Xyspade for the example given, you need `join()` otherwise there's a good chance the main method will execute the `println()` before the thread even executes - remembering that calling `start()` on a thread just *schedules* it to start, there's no guarantee *when* it will execute.  Your problem may be that you need to make your fields `volatile`, which ensures their values are not cached in other threads - and your main threads "sees" them change.

Comment: Actually, I've been looking into this, and it's possible that the problem may be elsewhere.  I will keep everyone updated.  Thanks once again.

Comment: Yes, this solution worked for me; the problem I was experiencing was elsewhere in the code.  Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

B is static, so only only exists at the class level, and can therefore not see instance variables of its parent class

```
public class A {
    String aString;  // <== instance variable

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        new Thread(b).start();
    }
    public static class B implements Runnable {  // <== static class
        public void run() {
            aString = "foo";
        }
    }
}
```

Possible fix. Make aString static too

```
public class A {
    static String aString;
```

Possible fix. Make B non-static. This is where it gets a bit weird. B now only exists at the instance level of A, so you need to create an A instance first.

```
public class A {
    String aString;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new A().new B();  // <== need to create an A before a B
        new Thread(b).start();
    }
    public class B implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            aString = "foo";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `B b = new A().new B();  // <== create via A`  - I've never seen this notation before - nice!

Comment: I only discovered it in the OCJP book, it's crazy isn't it!!?, a bit like Ruby's Object.new

Comment: @KevinDay that's because you very rarely need to create an instance of an inner class from outside the outer class

Answer (score 0):

You are asking an object instance of class B (which you create using `new B()` )to access a member variable of an object instance that you haven't created.  In your code, there is no object of class B created.

I think that you may be thinking that running the `main()` method in class A is somehow instantiating an instance of class A - this is not the case.

The following will work because you are creating an instance of A and making that available to your instance of B.

```
public class A {
    String aString;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B(a);
        new Thread(b).start();
    }
    public static class B implements Runnable {
        private final A a;

        public B(A a){
          this.a = a;
        }

        public void run() {
            a.aString = "foo";
        }
    }
}
```